# Аттестованный профессиональный спасатель

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая в том выражении не нужна, так как определения неоднородны. Слово АТТЕСТОВАННЫЙ относится к словосочетанию ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНЫЙ СПАСАТЕЛЬ. Вставка союза И между определениями невозможна.

Comment: Спасибо :)